# How do I fix this Android build failure? Failed to delete directory 'C:\Users\Name\Appdata\Local\Temp\vfs-14732somethingsomething?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build my project for a class assignment and I do not know why I am getting this build error. It makes very little sense to me.

Here's the entire message:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: com.android.jack.library.LibraryIOException: I/O error when accessing file 'C:\Users\Name\Downloads\Fall 2016\CSXXX\assignments\assignment1\app\build\intermediates\packaged\androidTest\debug\classes.zip': Failed to delete directory 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs-1473281485250-0'
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJack FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJack'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: com.android.jack.library.LibraryIOException: I/O error when accessing file 'C:\Users\Name\Downloads\Fall 2016\CSXXX\assignments\assignment1\app\build\intermediates\packaged\androidTest\debug\classes.zip': Failed to delete directory 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs-1473281485250-0'
```

Is this just a test failure? or is there a bigger issue?

Comment: Does that file exist? Can you delete that directory manually?

Comment: No, that file doesn't seem to exist in the folder specified?

Comment: Do you have that file or directory open in another application? Does the error persist after restarting the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, my Antivirus software seemed to be causing it.
I hope that [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212496) will be fixed within Android Studio soon.

Disabling antivirus altogether is obviously a bad idea, but if you can whitelist `%TEMP%/vfs*` in your antivirus it should do the trick (disclaimer: Do so at your own risk, this is still a bit of a security gap).

Alternatively you could [disable jack](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) and use the legacy toolchain for your Android project.